# Can "sub-linear" still be a straight line?

Tags: algorithms, performance, big-o

I'm working on a problem that requires a "sub-linear" solution.

A quick search for *sub-linear* will return a lot of this...

[image: Sub-linear #1]

... where the *sub-linear* line is modelled as [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)/asymptotic.

But I had come to understanding that *sub-linear* was anything that remained below the linear baseline, as the both tended towards infinity. In this plot...

[image: Sub-linear #2]

... the *sub-linear* result is still "linear-looking" (i.e. `y = mx + b`), but falls below the linear baseline.

So which is it? Does it have to be asymptotic/logarithmic? Or just trending away from the linear baseline solution?

Comment: Technically, sub-linear complexity includes constant complexity, and the graph for constant complexity is a horizontal straight line. But by definition all asymptotically straight lines represent linear complexity – whether a line “falls below” another is not considered relevant.

Comment: Your sub-linear result can be "linear-looking" dependng on how you look at it but it is not like y = mx + b.

Comment: Per definition, a sub-linear solution can never be linear, since, if it was, it would be linear and hence not sub-linear.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it cannot be. It looks like it can from this graph because it is a log-log plot, which means both the x and y axes are compressed. Any function which satisfies the relation y = a*x^c for some constants a and c will appear as a straight line in a log-log plot. So the simple answer is the "sub-linear" case is not a straight line.

This is evident from the legend too. The sub-linear case is labeled O(N^0.78). In a log-log plot, that would appear as a straight line with a slope of 0.78. However, it looks like this compared to a straight line in a regular plot: [image]

To be clear, it does not need to be logarithmic as you ask in the question. Any curve which grows slower than a straight line in the asymptotic case is sub-linear. A logarithmic curve is just an example.

Comment: Note the scale on the graph in this answer. This is a linear graph rather than a log-log graph as shown in the question.

Comment: @FabioTurati, note that the original plot was logarithmic on both axes ([log-log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot)). On a lin-log plot it would be the exponential that looks like a straight line.

Comment: @ilkkachu You are right. Sorry!

Comment: Yup, I didn't even notice the log-log scale on the second plot. I reckon I would have asked the question either way.

Answer (score 3):

> In this plot...
>
> [image: Sub-linear #2]
>
> ... the *sub-linear* result is still "linear-looking" (i.e. `y = mx + b`), but falls below the linear baseline.
>
> So which is it? Does it have to be asymptotic/logarithmic? Or just trending away from the linear baseline solution?

Notice the scales on both the pixels and time axes. They are uniformly spaced, but in a logarithmic sense. Time goes from 0.1 seconds to 10000 seconds, plotted uniformly by powers of ten, and pixels go from 30000 to ten million, also uniformly in a logarithmic sense. That makes this a log-log graph. These kinds of graphs can be very useful for looking at data that spans multiple orders of magnitudes.

Given a relationship of the form T = kP<sup>N</sup>, this will appear as log(T) = N log(P) + k on a log-log graph. In other words, even a sublinear relationship will appear to be linear, but with a slope that is less than that for a linear relationship. Similarly, a superlinear relationship will also appear to be linear, but with a slope greater than that of a linear relationship.